# TCPDF ERROR: Unable to Create Output File (Mac)

Tags: macos, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

I am able to use TCPDF without any problem in my local in Windows but I'm not able to use it in Mac.

I have the following:

```
$path_to_pdf = FCPATH.'assets/pdf/airdrop-'.$id.'.pdf';
$pdf_name = 'airdrop-'.$id.'.pdf';
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output($path_to_pdf, "F");
```

This gives me the absolute path:

```
/Users/elimariaaa/Sites/forexcargo_apps/assets/pdf/airdrop-38076.pdf
```

which is correct.

The permission of my Sites directory:

```
1028873 drwxr-xr-x  14 elimariaaa  staff      448 Nov 28 17:25 Sites
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **your file(FCPATH.'assets/pdf/airdrop-'.$id.'.pdf')** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the list-each function used by TCPDF that's deprecated with my PHP version. I replaced it with foreach and it's now working.